# Javascript getting body tag from page inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zend-framework, iframe

So here is my body and inside is an iframe that has its own body as well.

```
<body>
<div id="container_container"> 
<div id="header_container">
    <div id="logo_container"><br>
        <div id="auth">

        </div>
    </div>

</div> 

<div id="content_container">

    <div id="main_container">

        <div id="graphs_bom_container">
            <div id="form_upload"></div>

            <iframe id='my_iframe' name='my_iframe' src="" >
            <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>


            </body>
            </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

</div> 
</body>
```

So if i am returning from a controller to the iframe (writing something to it) and then I want to change the background image of the top 'body' tag not the one one the iframe. I can change the background image of the body on the iframe but not the main body tag up above.

This is what I have:

```
 document.body.style.backgroundImage='url(images/test.jpg)';;
```

So this changes the iframe body tag but I would like to reach the higher body tag at top for the whole page. Any suggestions? And need to do this using javascript only no jquery.

Bear in mind that i am return into an Iframe from the infamous ajax iframe file upload. Once the file upload (image in this case) is complete it should then change the background of current page.

Comment: document.getElementById('body') are you sure???

Comment: to get the parent document of the iframe you want `window.parent.document`

Comment: @PatrickEvans that might have worked. Will test again but that might seem like the answer. Feel free to write that as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you do like this

```
    document.body.style.backgroundImage='url(images/test.jpg)';
```

then it will set the background image of the whole page including the iframe body tag also.
One thing you can do is again change the background color of the body tag of iframe to the default white color.

```
   window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="white";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('my_iframe');
```

And To get the content document you can use:

```
var contDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
contDoc.style.backgroundImage='url(images/test.jpg)';
```

Comment: It returns as iframe is null.

Bear in mind that i am return into an Iframe from the infamous ajax iframe file upload. Once the file upload (image in this case) is complete it should then change the background of current page.